# Storing Cookies in Apache Server using Apache Module

Tags: apache, apache-modules

I am trying to write a Apache module where I can store a Cookie Value sent in response .

I want to send this back in the next requests.

I tried using the example from here

[Global variables in Apache Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329785/global-variables-in-apache-server)

But I cannot consistently retrieve the value. I can retrieve it some times but not all the time.

How do I make write this function. I am new to both C and Apache Modules.